# Increasing GWT Timeout on JBoss Server

Tags: gwt, jboss, timeout

We are working on a GWT based web application hosted on `JBoss 5.2.0.1`. We are using Java/Spring on the server side.

One of the Async services takes more than 5 minutes to return the response from the server, and this leads to error (on production environment):

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 504 
Gateway Time-out
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
```

The issue doesn't occur when the JBoss is hosted on my local machine. I am suspecting this is some server side setting on production environment which is causing the timeout.

I referred to a couple of questions on SO and the solutions are related to setting timeout with `RequestBuilder.setTimeoutMillis()`. However, I am not completely convinced that this is related to changes on client side (since the code works fine on my local, where only JBoss configuration may differ from the production)

Any pointers are appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Have a mercy on your users. 5 minutes is way too long. If you cannot cut it down to 5-10 seconds, you should make a call, return a response immediately, and then notify a user in a different manner when the task is completed.

Comment: I understand that, however that's how it's required to be done for now.

Comment: Most browsers have their own timeout settings. Firefox is 5 minutes, IE is 1 or 3 minutes, etc.  So even if you fix the server side, your users may not be able to complete requests.

Comment: Okay. If you have any idea about the server side fix, could you share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the there was a timeout set on the gateway. The gateway would return `HTTP 504` error in case there is no response returned by the server withing the set timeout (which was 5 minutes)